# Linear algebra done right 7.D.1

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products, positive-semidefinite

> Fix $u,x \in V$ with $u\ne 0$.  Define $T\in \mathcal L(V)$ by $$Tv = \langle v, u\rangle x$$ for every $v\in V$.  Prove that $$\sqrt{T^*T}v = \frac{\|x\|}{\|u\|}\langle v,u\rangle u$$ for every $v\in V$.

I try to use $\|Tv\|^2 = \langle Tv, Tv\rangle = \langle T^*Tv, v\rangle$ to relate this to $\sqrt{T^*T}$, but I got stuck. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to start by finding a formula for $T^*w$ by using $\langle T^*w,v\rangle = \langle w,Tv\rangle$ for all $v,w$.

Comment: But this only gives me $\langle Tv, Tv\rangle = \langle T^*Tv, v\rangle $, how should I relate that to $\ T^*T$ in order to describe the self-adjoint map.

Comment: Find $T^*w$, then compute $T^*T(v)=T^*(T(v))$ and figure out a linear map $S$ so that $S^2(v)=S(Sv) = T^*T(v)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're dealing with real vector spaces, you have, for any $v,w\in V$,
$$
\langle T^*Tv,w\rangle=
\langle Tv,Tw\rangle=
\langle \langle v,u\rangle x,\langle w,u\rangle x\rangle=
\langle v,u\rangle\langle w,u\rangle\langle x,x\rangle=
\langle \langle v,u\rangle\langle x,x\rangle u,w\rangle
$$
so
$$
T^*Tv=\langle v,u\rangle\langle x,x\rangle u
$$
Now, the map defined by
$$
S(v) = \frac{\|x\|}{\|u\|}\langle v,u\rangle u
$$
is self-adjoint (easy) and positive semidefinite because
$$
\langle v,S(v)\rangle=
\left\langle v,\frac{\|x\|}{\|u\|}\langle v,u\rangle u\right\rangle=
\frac{\|x\|}{\|u\|}\langle v,u\rangle^2\ge0
$$
Moreover
$$
S(S(v))=\frac{\|x\|}{\|u\|}\langle S(v),u\rangle u=
\frac{\|x\|}{\|u\|}\left\langle \frac{\|x\|}{\|u\|}\langle v,u\rangle u,u\right\rangle u=
\frac{\langle x,x\rangle}{\langle u,u\rangle}
  \langle v,u\rangle\langle u,u\rangle u
$$
so $S^2=T^*T$.

Comment: One possible typo just after 3rd equality in the first equation: It should be $\langle u,w\rangle$ instead of $\langle w,u\rangle$.

Comment: @Koro I don't see why: by definition $Tw=\langle w,u\rangle x$.

Comment: I meant this: $\langle \langle v,u\rangle x,\color{blue}{\langle w,u\rangle x\rangle} =\langle v,u\rangle \overline{\color{blue}{\langle w,u\rangle }} \langle x,x\rangle =\langle v,u\rangle \langle u,w\rangle \langle x,x\rangle $.

Comment: Ah, you have assumed real vector space,  in which case there is no typo.  I met this exercise today wherein there was no assumption whether vector space is complex or real so I had that in mind. :)